# How to properly encode in PEM an RSA private key encrypted with another RSA key?

Tags: rsa, pem

Say I have an RSA private key, if encoded in PEM, it usually looks like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
<base64 encoded bits>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If I encrypt the said key with a passphrase using AES, and then encode it in PEM, it should look like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,<IV hex>

<base64 encoded ciphertext>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Now, I would like to know what should go into the header if the key, encoded in base64 in the body, has been encrypted with another RSA (public) key? Is this specified in the PEM standard?

Comment: That header indicates that the file always contains an unencrypted RSA key (defined in an RFC, not sure which one). If you want an encrypted private key you have to use a different format. Please read the following article, it contains the basic details on the different formats https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem

Comment: @Robert: that's incorrect; for _PKCS8_ keys, the unencrypted and encrypted forms use different PEM labels and ASN.1 structures, but for the 'legacy' PKCS1 format with label `BEGIN/END RSA PRIVATE KEY` the encryption is done 'inside' just as shown. OP: The non-PKCS8 encryption was defined de facto by SSLeay / OpenSSL, based on but modified from PEM (RFC 1421 and 1423), and only allows symmetric ciphers. Asymmetric ciphers like RSA are generally useful only when different parties are involved (i.e. Alice != Bob) and a private key should never be held by more than one party (e,g, Alice).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Ok, so I guess the answer is that no such format was ever defined then. If you would like to expand a bit on that, maybe include some reference to your claims, I'd gladly accept that as an answer. As for the need to asymmetrically encrypt a private key, I believe I do have a very special case that standard PKI won't solve. Don't want to overcomplicate this question though, that's why I didn't include it in this question.

Comment: I don't know if there's a reference for a negative. You can see the predecessor PEM RFCs were for symmetric or hybrid encryption, but not pure asymmetric. And you can see the implementation in OpenSSL source in crypto/pem/pem_lib.c is only symmetric; the browsable repo on github appears to go back to 1998 though I'm not sure how complete it is for SSLeay/OpenSSL versions and of course it doesn't include the many forks and derivatives people have created, not to mention more-or-less compatible things in other languages.